Needing to rank order correlations from highest to lowest
Hello I have a very large data set in excel with many different variables. Some of the examples of independent variables are moisture percent at the time of harvesting corn, temperature the dryer when drying it down, rate of drying down to a certain moisture, and final moisture. I have many different hybrids and a large range of the independent variables. I also have the dependent variables (which is germination percentage scores). I am wanting to perform regression of all these things in order to rank order the levels of correlation from highest correlated to germ score, to lowest. It is a very large data set. What is the best way to do this?

What is your research question? Why are you talking about correlations and regression in the same question?
